# C# in Unity 3D/2D: Am I required to use Classes for every script?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

**A little background:** *I'm new to C# and Unity, but catching on very quickly.* I'm also hoping this thread will **not** spark a debate about the merits of classes and abstract coding, as that debate is **unrelated** and well-worn (and unnecessarily heated); so please keep that in mind.

I'm simply wondering if every C# script in Unity is required to have a main class in any way or for any reason.

Or instead, can methods, and variables can be written outside of a class in a blank file (with namespaces) to be used in a video game?

I'm asking because, when I create a new C# script, it seems to force a class into my file and I'm afraid of breaking things.

- *I hope to keep code abstraction to a minimum, and the current project
  I'm working on has several situations where a class is not needed, or
  only one instance of the class will be used. I'd like to simply avoid
  using classes in those cases.*

Comment: hi John, the simple answer is "yes, of course".  When you say *"I'd like to simply avoid using classes in those cases."*, just forget about that, it's completely meaningless.  Say you have some extremely simple task to achieve (what about "blink on and off").  OK, so it's one line of code, in a simple class called "Blink" in a file "Blink.cs".  That's all there is to it. Drop the file on the objects which need that "blink" behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, Joe Blow, all of these answers were very helpful and I struggled to pick the right one. I learned a lot and wish I could have picked all three answers.

Comment: well done, it's important for new users to Tick an answer!  you get points.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are.

In C#, things like global variables and functions just do not exist. *Everything* must be contained in a class.

"But what should I do in order to declare some stuff that can be accessed everywhere, without creating an object?" you asked. There is something called the *static modifier*. You can access the methods or variables or fields or properties marked with this modifier without creating an object of that class.

You just add the word `static` in a method and it becomes a static method! How simple!

Let's see an example.

I have this non-static method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void DoStuff () {

    }
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.DoStuff();
```

But if I modify it with `static`,

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void DoStuff () {

    }
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
MyClass.DoStuff();
```

How convenient!

Note:

Please do not misuse the static modifier! **Only use it when it makes sense! When? When the method is a utility method or when the method does not belong to individual objects but the class itself.**

Comment: Are you trying to sell something? Please do not use these rhetorical "how convenient / how simple" questions, they don't belong into a answer. Also, global vars actually do exists, but only declared inside a class.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of declaring/defining variables and methods outside of any class, [you can't really do that in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717348/why-do-c-sharp-and-java-require-everything-to-be-in-a-class). It just isn't how the language was designed (the answers to the question I linked to expand on that idea, so I won't duplicate them here).

You're not without options, though; if you have a number of variables or methods that need to be accessible from different places and don't need an object reference, you can make them `static`, so you won't need to instantiate the class to make use of them:

```
public class UtilityClass
{
    public static float GravityConstant = 3.51f;
    public static string GameName = "MyFirstGame";

    public static float CalculateProduct(float a, float b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Then, you can reference the class's methods/members by accessing it through its name:

```
float product = UtilityClass.CalculateProduct(6, 1.5f);
```

An example of where you might use this pattern is when defining mathematical formulae which aren't included in Unity's `Mathf` methods, and using them in multiple classes.

*Additional note: Creating a new C# script through Unity's editor UI will default to declaring a class of the same name that inherits from `Monobehaviour`. You can alter it to remove the inheritance from `Monobehaviour` if you don't need any of the methods/attributes of the class, which avoids unnecessary overhead. One example for this would be with a static class that you never need to instantiate.*

Answer (score 1):

1. First of All you need to check where [Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) define as offical
   docs stated

   > "**Methods are declared** **in a class or struct** by specifying the access
   >   level such as public or private...."

   So, Method should be declare in a Class or struct and [A given class
   should be, ideally, responsible for just one task.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/coding-practices)([see also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))
2. Your this question ***"Or instead, can methods, and variables can be
   written outside of a class in a blank file (with namespaces) to be
   used in a video game?"*** answer is hidden in the below question.

   **[Can there be stand alone functions in C# without a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916718/can-there-be-stand-alone-functions-in-c-sharp-without-a-class)?**
   *No. Make them static and put them in a static utility class if they indeed don't fit within any of your existing classes.*

   You have to make a class in order to use methods or its variable
   either instance class or static class.
3. **Am I required to use Classes for every script?** Every script means you required a class. Unity Support **[Component Based
   Architectural Design](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/oop-vs-component-based-architectural-design.216532/)** and if you require any script related
   work then you definitely require a script component which means a
   class require.
4. Finally for [singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton), thanks to Unity3dWiki great detail
   available. I think you will be feel comfortable to code and writing
   class if you keep in mind component based architecture of Unity3d.
5. **Singleton vs Static**: I will also recommend to check this: [Why do you use a Singleton class
   if a Static class serves the purpose](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/singleton-vs-static-classes/)

Hope it will help.

*[Note: If this helpful Any one can update this answer for future reference and use].*